# Best-Practices for using schemas in SQL Server (2008)

Tags: sql-server, schema

I can see in the AdventureWorks database that different schemas are used to group tables. Why is this done (security, ...?) and are there best-practices I can find?

thx, Lieven Cardoen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practices for using Schemas in SQL 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452048/best-practices-for-using-schemas-in-sql-2005)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As a manager of Business Intelligence, we rely on schema for logical grouping and managing security.  Here are some cases as to how we use schema:

**LOGICAL ORGANIZATION**

1. We have a general database that is loaded by SSIS packages solely for staging data before we load our operational data store (ODS).  In this database, with the exception of the schema all objects are indentical in structure (table names, column names, data types, nullability, etc.) to their original source.  We use the schema to indicate the original source system of the table.  In some rare instances, two different databases have tables with the same name and schema allows us to continue to use the original name in the staging database.
2. In every database on our BI servers each team member has a test_username schema.  When we create test objects in a database, this makes it easy to keep track of who made the object.  It also makes it a lot easier to purge the test objects later since everyone knows who made what.  Frankly, just knowing that we made it is usually enough to know it can be deleted safely, especially when we can't remember when or why we made it!
3. In our data controller database, we rely on schema to separate different types of processes between reports, etl, and generic resources.
4. In our star schema data warehouse, all objects are devided into dimension and fact schemas.
5. When we push data to other departmental servers, we make all BI objects on their servers use the schema bi.  This makes it REALLY easy to know bi loads and maintains the table even though it isn't on our server.  If the target server isn't a 2008/2005 SQL Server box, then we prefix the table with bi_.

When it gets down to it, we use schema for logical organization anytime we WOULD have appended a prefix or suffix to an object to help organize it in the absence of schema.  Having said this, there are a few instances where we don't use schema on our BI servers.  In our WorkingDB, everything is dbo.  Our WorkingDB is used like TempDB to create temporary tables, but these tables are temporary tables that we know we will create everytime an ETL process runs.  The special property of WorkingDB is that we don't ever backup the database and all ETL processes that use the database must be able to recreate their objects from scratch in the absence of the table.  In this instance, we felt using schema didn't add ANY organizational value since we don't actually use the objects outside of their temporary ETL process.

**SECURITY**

1. Since we are a BI group, we don't generally build and support our own applications.  We almost exclusively use other people's applications and bring data from their back-end databases to our server.  However, we do have one database called bi_applications that is the back-end for a variety of small CRUD applications.  These applications are usually data entry forms that we provide to the business so that they can capture data we would otherwise have to maintain in BI.  It is a way of getting data that should be in production applications into BI while we wait for our low priority application enhancements to gather dust in the future development lists.  Each application has a separate schema and the application account used to update the underlying tables ONLY has access to objects of the associated schema.  This makes it really easy to understand, secure, and maintain the separate applications.
2. In a few instances, I have let power users have direct database access to our tables or stored procedures.  We rely on using schema combined with roles to secure the objects.  We grant permissions to the schema and users are added to roles.  This allows us to easily understand which objects are used by whom without having to dig through roles to figure it out.

In short, we use schema for security purposes when we probably would have considered separating the objects out into their own databases and when we expect an application or user outside of BI to access our databases.

Although these aren't best business practices for application developers, I hope my bi use-cases may help you think of some of the ways to use schema in your end of the business.